# SQLite timestamp conversion function

Tags: sqlite, date, timestamp

I've inherited a SQLite DB, in it I've a TIMESTAMP field called ZDATE.

One value is 401,580,000 and I know it correspond to Sept 23rd, 2013.

I've calculated that the 0 of this field is the midnight of Jan 1st, 2001 (?).

However, I didn't find any conversion function to get a formatted date, in fact if I use **date()** I get:

```
  ZDATE            date(zdate)
401580000      1094776-12632211-20
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> select 401580000 / (julianday('2013-09-23') - julianday('2001-01-01'));
86398.4509466437
> select 60*60*24;
86400
```

So this timestamp appears to use seconds.

To convert it into a timestamp that [SQLite can use directly](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), i.e., a Unix epoch timestamp, just add the appropriate offset:

```
> select datetime(401580000 + strftime('%s', '2001-01-01 02:00:00'), 'unixepoch');
2013-09-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I also added 7200 so it correctly return midnight of 2013-09-23

Comment: Any idea about why starting it at Jan 1st, 2001 ? It's a DB used by an iOS application

Comment: 2001 is the year of the release of Mac OS X 10.0.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)